# If constructor of StringBuilder is passed with string literals then how many objects are created

Tags: concatenation, stringbuilder

**Question 1:**

In this code, is there Just only one string object is created, or one string object along with 5 String literals (`"abc"`, `"xyz"`, `"abcxyz"`, `"123"`, `"abcxyz123"`)?

```
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("abc"+"xyz"+"123");
```

**Question 2:**

In this other case, is there only one string object created?

```
 StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder();  
       s2.append("abc");  
       s2.append("xyz");  
       s2.append("123");
```

Comment: Are you asking that since you are passing in String literals in as parameters for the String Builder, are those getting added into the String pool as they are read?

Answer (score 0):

Since strings are immutable, when you use the `+` operator with two strings, you create a new string object with the concatenation. The [string pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) serves as optimization, so if it contains the string, the reference is returned instead of creating a new one.

The [`intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) method adds the String object to the pool if it does not already contain it. **String literals are always interned**, so in both questions you are creating the same number of references and adding them to the string pool (used in the constructor or as arguments).

Note that it would be different for creating string objects: When we use `s = new String("foo");`, we are creating a new reference, so in that case the string object won't be in the string pool until you call `s.intent()`.

Comment: A.Rodas:- Yes i wanted to know when we pass string literals to Stringbuilder then are they added in String pool and using + operator in StringBuilder constructor also creates new strings.

Comment: @ShaileshSG Creating a string and adding it to the string pool are different things, I've edited the answer to include it.